# Error with jdbc-river

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm trying to load data into elasticsearch with a jdbc-river, and I'm getting this error.  Can someone tell me what's going on?

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [foo] tried to parse as object, but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:467)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:515)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:462)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:371)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:400)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:153)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-03-19 22:06:06,672][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth] bulk [11790] success [100 items] [15ms]
```

Here is the river definition:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_river/_meta' -d '{
              "type" : "jdbc"
              , "jdbc" : {
                    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://domainname.com:5432/myapp"
                    , "user": "user"
                    , "password": "passwd"
                    , "sql": "select * from foo"
                    , "index": "myapp"
                    , "type": "foo"
                    }
              }'
```

There is no elasticsearch mapping yet.  Perhaps that's a problem.  My understanding was that it maps automatically, but I'm willing to add any mapping if necessary.

postgres table schema ("datatype", "is_nullable"):

```
"integer";"YES"
"boolean";"NO"
"boolean";"YES"
"character varying";"NO"
"timestamp with time zone";"YES"
"text";"YES"
"boolean";"NO"
"integer";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"text";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"date";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"boolean";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"timestamp with time zone";"NO"
"timestamp with time zone";"NO"
"boolean";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"numeric";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"character varying";"YES"
"integer";"YES"
"integer";"NO"
"integer";"NO"
```

Comment: What is the query that you are using and associated table schema?

Comment: Provide information about mapping, query etc..

Comment: @pickypg and BlackPOP, I added what I think your are asking for to the question.  Let me know if there's anything else that would help.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ballpark Did you solve your problem?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @JulienPalard and eliasah, I added my solution though it's not through a river.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using a river.  I used the elasticsearch API through a python client to post documents to elasticsearch from the application server (our application is Python).  This works good.  I used the python's multiprocessing features to improve load times with 20 processes.  It's loading about 28,000 documents in a couple minutes.

I hope this helps!